# from NSFetchedResults objectAtIndex:0 returning 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I've been banging my head on this one specific issue for about 2 hours now, reading through documentation and examples and I just can't wrap my head around it. I have core data models Person and Photo, and they're linked. I'm trying to display a UITableView with the contents and

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

keeps returning 0. Here is the relevant code.
I know there is data in my core data because I can look at it with sqlite in terminal.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface PaparazziAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;

    UITabBarController *tabController;
    UINavigationController *mainNavController;
    UINavigationController *recentsNavController;
    PersonListViewController  *personListView;
    PhotoListViewController *recentsList;
    PhotoDetailViewController *photoDetail;

    FlickrFetcher *fetcher;
    NSManagedObjectContext *currentContext;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *mainNavController, *recentsNavController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "PaparazziAppDelegate.h"

@implementation PaparazziAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize tabController, mainNavController, recentsNavController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   

    // Setup the database instances for access.
    fetcher = [FlickrFetcher sharedInstance];

    // Check to see if the database exists, if not, load the plist and populate.
    if ([fetcher databaseExists])
        NSLog(@"I'm here!");
    else {
        NSLog(@"No database yet!");

        currentContext = [fetcher managedObjectContext];

        /* -- REMOVED FOR READABILITY -- 
        A chunk of code for creating fresh data from a plist if the database doesn't yet exist.
        I know this part works because I can see the data using the terminal */

        [currentContext release];
    }
    // End of the plist loading and database creation.

    personListView = [[PersonListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    personListView.title = @"Contacts";
    [mainNavController pushViewController:personListView animated:NO];
    [personListView release];

    recentsList = [[PhotoListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoListViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    recentsList.title = @"Recents";
    [recentsNavController pushViewController:recentsList animated:NO];
    [recentsList release];

    // setting up view icons
    UITabBarItem *contactsIcon = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                          initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:0];
    mainNavController.tabBarItem = contactsIcon;
    [contactsIcon release];
    UITabBarItem *recentsIcon = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                                  initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemRecents tag:0];
    recentsNavController.tabBarItem = recentsIcon;
    [recentsIcon release];

    [self.window addSubview:tabController.view];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [tabController release];
    [mainNavController release];
    [recentsNavController release];

    [fetcher release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

PersonListViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FlickrFetcher.h"
#import "Person.h"
#import "Photo.h"

@interface PersonListViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *listOfPeople;

    FlickrFetcher *fetcher;
    NSManagedObjectContext *currentContext;
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listOfPeople;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *currentContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end
```

And the trouble file, PersonListViewController.m

```
#import "PersonListViewController.h"

@implementation PersonListViewController

@synthesize listOfPeople, currentContext, fetchedResultsController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
        fetcher = [FlickrFetcher sharedInstance];
        currentContext = [fetcher managedObjectContext];

        fetchedResultsController = [fetcher fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Contacts";
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.    
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    Person *person = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [person name];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something simple or 1 off, but I just can't seem to find it.
[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] returns a singleton, if I toss a few breakpoints into each .m file, I can see that the object id of *fetcher in each area is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't used [performFetch:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW6) to execute the fetched results controller's request. `viewWillAppear:` is usually a good place to do it:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"fetch error: %@", error);
    }
 }
```

Comment: *facedesk* *facedesk* *facedesk* That was it, in trying to track a possibly missing reference I forgot about performFetch. And now it works, thank you so much. As an aside if anyone sees anything stupid wrong with my releases feel free to yell at me.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside - you might consider initialising your fetchedResultsController in `viewDidLoad` rather than `initWithStyle:`, then you can drop it in `viewDidUnload` and hence free up some memory if the OS needs to unload the view controller.